# Condição if com JavaScript dentro do PHP

Tags: php, javascript

É possível verificar se a variável está `null` no trecho JS no PHP?

```
<?php
print("<SCRIPT language=javascript> 

            string_patr = \"$string_patr\";
            string_seri = \"$string_seri\";
            if(string_patr == null){
                vv_patr = string_seri;
            }
            else{
                vv_patr = string_patr+','+ string_seri;
            }
            alert(vv_patr);


        </SCRIPT>");


?>
```

Comment: qual é o erro??

Comment: O erro é que o `if(string_patr == null)` não reconhece se está null ou não! E ele está tudo no php'

Comment: @Alexandre, prefira [edit] a pergunta para adicionar informações/esclarecer dúvidas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Verificar no lado do PHP

Com base no código presente na pergunta, o mais simples é verificares com PHP o conteúdo das variáveis, preparando assim o valor a ser usado pelo JavaScript no lado do cliente:

```php
if (is_null($string_patr)) {
    $vv_patr = $string_seri;
}
else {
    $vv_patr = $string_patr.','.$string_seri;
}

echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
  var vv_patr = "'.$vv_patr.'";
  alert(vv_patr);
</script>';
```

*Exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/DwyBzQ).*

Desta forma o PHP verifica as variáveis e quando é para enviar o código de JavaScript para o navegador, vai menos código e já pronto a ser utilizado.

Saber mais sobre a função [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) de PHP.

---

## Verificar no lado do JavaScript

Para manteres o teu código com a lógica no lado do JavaScript, será necessário alterar a maneira como verificas o conteúdo da variável.

O `null` na variável PHP vai-se refletir em *nada* na variável de JavaScript.

```php
$string_patr = null;
$string_seri = "bubu";

print("<SCRIPT language=javascript>
string_patr = \"$string_patr\";
string_seri = \"$string_seri\";
if(string_patr == null){
vv_patr = string_seri;
}
else{
vv_patr = string_patr+','+ string_seri;
}
alert(vv_patr); 
</SCRIPT>");
```

Vai resultar em:

```html
<SCRIPT language=javascript> 
    string_patr = "";
    string_seri = "bubu";
    if(string_patr == null){
        vv_patr = string_seri;
    }
    else{
        vv_patr = string_patr+','+ string_seri;
    }
    alert(vv_patr);
</SCRIPT>
```

Repara que o `null` no lado do PHP acabou por ser *nada* no lado do JavaScript. Como tens aspas duplas, acabas por ficar com `string_patr = "";` o que te permite alterar a verificação para:

```js
 if ((!string_patr || string_patr.length === 0) {
    vv_patr = string_seri;
 }
 else {
    vv_patr = string_patr+','+ string_seri;
 }
```

Assim estamos a ver se a variável efetivamente existe e não está vazia.

**Nota:** O tipo de verificação depende do que é esperado estar na variável, na verificação em cima sugerida está-se a verificar se ela é `null`, `undefined` ou vazia.

Answer (score 2):

Experimente antes assim:

```
<?php
    echo "<SCRIPT> 
                string_patr = ".$string_patr.";
                string_seri = ".$string_seri.";
                if(string_patr == null){
                    vv_patr = string_seri;
                }
                else{
                    vv_patr = string_patr+','+ string_seri;
                }
                alert(vv_patr);
    </SCRIPT>";
?>
```

Comment: Mas essa é a maneira de ir direto pelo `JS`, e eu preciso executar esse trecho no `PHP` quando entra na página!

Comment: já alterei, por favor confirme

Comment: Não vai resultar, se `$string_patr` é `null`, o que vai ser enviado para o navegador vai ser: `string_patr = ;`. A verificação de `null` numa variável PHP tem que ser feita no lado do PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language=javascript> 

   function isNullCustom(test) 
   {
       return (test == null || test == "null" || typeof(test) == "undefined" || test == "");
   }

   var string_patr = "<?php echo $string_patr; ?>";
   var string_seri = "<?php echo $string_seri; ?>";

   if(isNullCustom(string_patr))
   {
      vv_patr = string_seri;
   }
   else
   {
      vv_patr = string_patr+','+string_seri;
   }

   alert(vv_patr);

</script>
```

Acredito que o problema não está no php. Quando você imprime ***null*** em uma variavel javascript, ela não é um valor boleano, mas sim uma string com o texto '***null***'.

Criei uma função customizada para identificação de possíveis casos de null para o que você quer.

Onde, uma variável que se encontre como:

- boleana *null*;
- string *null*;
- string vazia (0 caracteres);
- ou com seu tipo indefinido;

Serão consideradas nulas.

Veja se funciona.